# AuthorizationHandlerContext context returns context.User.Identity.Name null

Tags: blazor, authorization

I'm building Blazor Server application, that will be used only by a couple of employees of a company. While creating app, I'v chosen Windows Authentication. It was working fine, showing user name on the page. Then I wanted to add authorization based on username, so that my app would be available only for chosen employees. As a source of usernames that should be authorized I use SQL Server Database (used by another company software).

My requirement class:

```
public class AuthorizedEmpsRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public List<string> AuthorizedEmployees { get; set; }

    public AuthorizedEmpsRequirement(List<string> authorizedEmployees)
    {
        AuthorizedEmployees = authorizedEmployees;
    }
}
```

My requirementHandler class:

```
    public class AuthorizedEmpsHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AuthorizedEmpsRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AuthorizedEmpsRequirement requirement)
    {
        var userName = context.User.Identity.Name;

        if (requirement.AuthorizedEmployees.Contains(userName))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

My Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AuthorizedEmpsHandler>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("EmpRights", policy =>
    policy.Requirements.Add(new AuthorizedEmpsRequirement(AuthorizedEmps.AuthorizedEmployees(builder.Configuration))));
}
```

And now I don't only have no authorization, but also lost my authentication.

This view once showed my username, now it is epmty.

```
    <AuthorizeView Policy="EmpRights">
    Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name
    </AuthorizeView>
```

On page.razor I get username correctly by attempting it this way:

```
<p>@AuthorizedEmps.AuthorizedEmployees(Configuration)[0]</p>
```

But in my requirementHandler context.User.Identity.Name returns null.

I'm a beginner in .NET world, so I would appreciate every piece of advice.

P.S. I'm using IConfiguration Configuration because I take my connectionString to the database from appsettings.json.